# How do erase unnecessary things from the output?

Tags: python

I'm working on crawling with Python.

It works normally, but I want to erase unnecessary information in the output.

How do I erase it?

---

## my attempt

- replace
- split

split, replace was used, but did not work on the list.

---

### output

```
https://www.lawtalk.co.kr/qna/179313-%EC%83%81%EA%B0%84%EB%85%80-%EC%9E%85%EC%9E%A5%EC%97%90%EC%84%9C-%EC%9C%A0%EB%B6%80%EB%82%A8%EC%9D%B8%EC%A7%80-%EB%AA%A8%EB%A5%B4%EA%B3%A0-%EB%A7%8C%EB%82%AC%EC%8A%B5%EB%8B%88%EB%8B%A4
```

### my golas

```
https://www.lawtalk.co.kr/qna/179313
```

> How can extracted like the output of mygolas?

Comment: `print(arr[0].split("-")[0])`

Comment: you can use a regex for finding a pattern and then extracting the value you need

Comment: @MrHola21 or just use `str.split()`. That's what it's there for. No need for regex.

Comment: i sovle. thx!!!

Comment: @MattDMo Yaa You  can do that but as he said that he had tried with .split() , I offered him an alternative

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you

```
arr = []
for elem in elems:
    href = elem.get_attribute("href")
    href_split = href.split('-')
    arr.append(href_split[0])

print(arr[0])
```